# How to change the position of toggle button in TEXTINPUTLAYOUT?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

Hey I'm working with material design dependency and having a problem that **how I change the position of toggle button in TEXTINPUTLAYOUT**? As seen in below image the word *password* is not align with *password toggle button*

Thanks

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tiet_s_pwd"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
    app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/white"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextColor="@color/primarydark"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="#3030"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/hguide_s_12"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vguide_s_4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vguide_s_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/hguide_s_10">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/text"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pb"
        android:textColor="#303030"
        android:textColorHint="#50303030"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Without any indication what you tried and what you would expect to happen, it is very difficult to guess, what knowledge others could share to help you, except the obvious to read the docs (which is actually great advice if you haven't done soe). Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Comment: What you tried to solve it? please consider uploading code.

Comment: @ShoaibKhalid This doesn't need code; what it needs is a clear explanation.  HEET: Are you referring to the _password_ toggle?

Answer (score 0):

For normal setup the toggle button will be aligned center. I think it is caused by the `padding` setting?

Try to remove or adjust your `padding` of your `TextInputEditText`:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/text"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pb"
```